# Firebase database returns null; upon refresh, it returns correct value

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I've searched the existing discussions to no avail, so I thought I'd ask the community for assistance: I'm using JavaScript to fetch data from a Firebase database. The initial fetch works well; however, when I add a child to the database, my JavaScript webpage receives the new child data *initially* as "null". The strange thing is that if I refresh the webpage, the "null" is replaced by the correct data.

Here's my source for the webpage:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Reading Firebase Database</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../d3.js"></script>
        <style type="text/css">
            /* No style rules here yet */       
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>

    <div id="div1">
    </div>

        <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.9.0/firebase.js"></script>
        <script>

            // Initialize Firebase
            var config = {
                apiKey: confidential,
                authDomain: confidential,
                databaseURL: confidential,
                projectId: confidential,
                storageBucket: confidential,
                messagingSenderId: "confidential"
            };
            firebase.initializeApp(config);

            // Read Firebase Data
            var database = firebase.database().ref().child("session");
            database.on("child_added", snap => {
            var dur = snap.child("dur").val();
            var lat = snap.child("lat").val();
            var lon = snap.child("lon").val();

            // Display Firebase Data
            var para = document.createElement("p");
            var node = document.createTextNode(lon);
            para.appendChild(node);
            var element = document.getElementById("div1");
            element.appendChild(para);

            });

        </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

And here is the Firebase outline:

[image: Screenshot of Firebase data]

Thank you, in advance, for your help. I really appreciate it.

Comment: That should work. Have you tried using `session` as a reference instead?  `var database = firebase.database().ref("session");`

Comment: I'm afraid that didn't work.

Comment: Same thing happens with me on adding a new child . The data come after refreshing the page. So I have to use `on('value')` function along with `child_added`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use `on('value')` function to get the value of each child . So whenever a new child is added `on('value')` will run for each child in firebase.

```
var database = firebase.database().ref().child("session");
database.on("value", snap => {
    snap.forEach(snapshot => {
        if ChildKey == newKey {
            console.log(snapshot.val())
        }
    })
});
```

Comment: Thanks very much!